# CSS Backgrounds and Borders Module Level 3 property error

Tags: css, premailer

```html
<a href="/" class="rounded-md">Navigate</a>
```

Rounded md is [tailwind](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/border-radius) for 0.375rem

The error is from premailer/cssutils:

`transform(html)`

```
Property: Invalid value for "CSS Backgrounds and Borders Module Level 3" property: 
0.375rem [1:1: border-radius]
```

Not sure how to parse this. Rems are valid as far as I can tell. The CSS applies fine in the browser.

Comment: we need to see the code

Comment: Have you used your browser's devtools inspect facility to see exactly what CSS is being produced here?

Comment: Hey thanks for the comments. I updated the description and yes the CSS looks great in the browser (both in devtools and the resulting UI). My issue is surfacing from CSSUTILS on the backend.